# I want to type x = 499 in the input line, is it right?, is there any way

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
x = 499
z = int(input('Here is it readable {} ? : ').format(x))
```

Here is the code (above), I want to type the value of x in place of {} in the z, is there any way?

Comment: You closed the parentheses too early.

Comment: Put `format()` _inside_ `input()`; i.e., `input('Here ...'.format(x))`. Better, use f-string.

Answer (score 1):

`.format()` is supposed to be called on strings. You placed the parenthesis incorrectly in your code.

```py
x = 499
z = int(input('Here is it readable {} ? : '.format(x)))
```

This correction produces:

```
>>> z = int(input('Here is it readable {} ? : '.format(x)))
Here is it readable 499 ? :
```

Comment: @blank Oh silly mistake *facepalm*. Thanks for help

Answer (score -1):

You can do this:

```
x = 499
z = int(input(f"Now that is visible {x}, is it not?(0\1): "))
```

That should work. Do tell if not.

Comment: yep it works, Thanks for the help *silly Mistake*. Have a nice day

Comment: Always welcome! ;)